# Inline edit a hyperlink using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('.edit_button').click(function(){
            console.log($(this).siblings().text());
            modifications($(this));
        });            
    });

    function modifications(cell){
        var form = '<form> <input type="text" id = "newText" size = "30" value='+cell.siblings().text()+'></form>';

        cell.parent('td').append(form).focus();
        cell.parent().children('.link').toggle();
        $('#newText').keypress(function (e) {

            if (e.which == 13) {
                console.log("form submitted");
                e.preventDefault();

                var new_text = cell.parent('td').children('#newText').val();
                //Show hyperlink with new value
                cell.parent().children('.link').toggle();
                cell.parent().children('.link').text(new_text);
                //Hide text box
                cell.parent().children('.newText').hide();
            }
        });   
    }

    </script>

    </head>
        <body>
          <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>E-Mail</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sergey brin</td>
                <td>Google</td>
                <td class="email"> 
                    <a class = "link" href= "www.gmail.com" > sergey.brin@gmail.com </a> 
                    <button class = "edit_button" type="button" style = "float:right" >Edit !</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Elon Musk</td>
                <td> Amazon </td>
                <td class="email"> 
                    <a class = "link" href = "www.spacex.com">elon.musk@spacex.com </a>
                    <button class= "edit_button" type="button" style = "float:right">Edit !</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Bill Gates </td>
                <td> Microsoft </td>
                <td class="email"> 
                    <a class = "link" href = "www.microsoft.com"> bill.gates@hotmail.com </a>
                    <button class="edit_button" type="button" style = "float:right">Edit !</button>               
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>    
    </body>          

</html>
```

**Problem Statement :**
I want a textbox to appear when edit button is clicked, and after editing when enter is pressed the contents of the textbox should change to hyperlink, else if Escape is pressed original contents of the hyperlink should be restored.

What am I missing here? I am not even able to fetch value from the textbox.
Can somebody brainstorm with me?

Comment: You should really revise the Basics of HTML.  Your `<body>` is inside `<table>`. Fix that.

Comment: Proper HTML: http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=LyFkqtaC

Comment: @shrinivas I have modified the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution.

```js
$(function(){
    $('table').delegate('.edit_button', 'click', function (e) {
        var target = $(this);
        var link = target.siblings('.link');
        var input;
        
        if (target.siblings('.newText').length === 0) {
            target.before('<input type="text" class="newText" size="30" value='+link.text()+'>');
            link.toggle();
          
            input = target.siblings('.newText');
            input.focus();
            input.keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which === 13) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    link.text(input.val()).toggle();
                    input.remove();
                } else if (e.which === 0) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    link.toggle();
                    input.remove();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>E-Mail</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sergey brin</td>
        <td>Google</td>
        <td class="email"> 
            <a class="link" href="www.gmail.com" > sergey.brin@gmail.com </a> 
            <button class="edit_button" type="button" style="float:right" >Edit !</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Elon Musk</td>
        <td> Amazon </td>
        <td class="email"> 
            <a class="link" href="www.spacex.com">elon.musk@spacex.com </a>
            <button class="edit_button" type="button" style="float:right">Edit !</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Bill Gates </td>
        <td> Microsoft </td>
        <td class="email"> 
            <a class = "link" href = "www.microsoft.com"> bill.gates@hotmail.com </a>
            <button class="edit_button" type="button" style = "float:right">Edit !</button>   
        </td>
    </tr>    
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You made something invalid, even the `HTML` part! the valid structure of an `HTML` file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- you may load some css and/or js files here -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- here you can add your html elements, such as `table`, `div`, and so on -->
    </body>
</html>
```

So, you need first fix this, as first job !

Also try `.prev()`, instead of `siblings()`, as below:

```
cell.prev().text();
```

And make below changes:

```
$('table').delegate('#newText', 'keypress', function (e) {
    // rest of code
}
```